# Java - Clients won't receive data from server despite server receiving data from clients

Tags: java, sockets, printwriter

I've got a fairly simple multi-thread chat program, where a server receives data from multiple clients and is then supposed to relay the messages back to all clients.

While the server does receive all its data properly, I can't seem to make the clients receive the returned values.

I've read through plenty of code and suggestions from both StackOverflow and other forums, but I can't seem to find the issue.

The ServerThread has the PrintWriter "out", declared and grabbed as such:

```
private PrintWriter out;

public PrintWriter getWriter(){
        return out;
    }

public void run() {
        try{
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

This method in the ServerThread is supposed to pass the data along:

```
if(input != null){
                    //Loggs message to file:
                    loggMessage(input);
                    //Loggs message to Server GUI
                    setOutput(input);
                    //Prints message to Output
                    System.out.println(input);
                    //Sends message to other clients:
                    for(ServerThread c : UserList){
                        System.out.println("Client discovered");
                        PrintWriter clientwriter = c.getWriter();
                        clientwriter.write(input);
                        System.out.print(input + " <-- was written to client");
                    }
                }
```

The console (and file) get all messages as expected, but the clients don't. This is, as far as I can tell, either caused by something being off with that line in this batch of code, or something being wrong clientside

Clientside:

```
in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

The "in" is declared like that, a few rows before the following chunk of code:

```
if(in.ready()){
                    String serverin = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println(serverin);
                    setOutput(serverin);
                }
```

This system.out.print doesn't print anything. This makes me believe that something is wrong already at the if, but I'm not sure what that would be.

So, the clients won't receive the messages, and I'm not sure why.
When the program is run, the server indicates that all clients have been found and messages appropriately, yet they won't receive anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this call to in.ready() is wrong.

```
if(in.ready()){
                    String serverin = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println(serverin);
                    setOutput(serverin);
                }
```

There is no need to call ready() because in.readline() will wait(block) until there is input.

An other issue is that readline() will wait(block) until the server send a newline, and only return the string once it gets a newline so are you sure that input contains a newline?

Comment: While I think you might be right, I'm not sure what I should replace them with. By removing the if(in.ready()) I determined that the issue is probably caused by the readLine, as the program never made it past this line when run without the if-clause.

To me, this suggests that the if-clause was never actually triggered before, meaning that it should indeed have gone, but also that the readLine() should be replaced by something else.

in.read() only returns and int, so that's not quite it either.

Comment: As a start: On the server try to add "\r\n" to what you send to the client. Then readline might return a full line of text.

Read reads a single byte at a time, and return -1 if the connection is closed. So if readline still don't work try 

If that don't work, try to replace readline() on the client with: while(true) { int val=in.read(); System.out.println(val); if(val==-1) break; }

Comment: By removing the if-clause the program now crashes as soon as it tries to interpret the "input" string, as it is null when the program launches. I tried to fix this by surrounding it with a new if-clause, so that it only reads when the in.read() != -1, but this doesn't seem to work either, as the program still freezes on launch. I'll mess around with it a bit more and see if any other combination might work out.

Answer (score 0):

So, after quite a lot of testing and comparing code, I've finally found the issue.

The "clientwriter.write(input)" should have been "clientwriter.println(input)". After changing that the whole system worked as intended.